# Running xml test suite with jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I know how to configure Jenkins to run a particular test class using mvn -Dtest = nameoftest test in my windows batch command. However, how can I run a xml script that contains many tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who stumbles upon this, you run an xml file via jenkins like this..

```
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile = src/whatever/path/my_file.xml
```